# Failed to run textured cc3node in Cocos3d

Tags: ios, xcode, blender, cocos3d

I have developed a 3d ground, a plane node, using Blender 2.66. I added the pod file with the texture image in resources folder.But when i run, can't find the object it self !!!

I can find it works nice when i render in blender. Then why does this happen ??

I checked some similar questions, but can't find a satisfying answer.

Here is the screenshot of ground node in PVRShareman

[image]
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use programm called [PVRShaman](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-pvrshaman.asp) to know how you ground looks like and where is it placed.

and after that just use:

```
CC3PODResourceNode *node = [CC3PODResourceNode nodeFromFile: @"you_file.pod"];
[self addChild:node];
```

you can change it position by 
node.location = cc3v( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );

there is two problem you can have, wrong position of you camera, or wrong position in pod file, check in blender what you object placed in (0,0,0)

for example if you object in blender have position (10,0,0)
to center in cocos3d you need to set object `location = cc3v(-10.0,0,0);`

so best way is to have object placed in (0,0,0)

Comment: My Node is at (0,0,0) in blender

Comment: check what you model has a texture in PVRShaman, example http://imgur.com/mEt86XA

Comment: i didn't get in cocos3d, when i run

Comment: so if you add object without texture all is ok?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31176/discussion-between-karan-alangat-and-ices-2)